# why Selenium Ruby for testing?

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, project

The project I am working on is a Enterprise application built using Java. However Ruby Selenium is used to test the application. I have asked my work mates why we use Ruby Selenium as apposed to Java and they do not seem to have a clue its been there since they have started, they believe that it might be because its Rubys is faster tha Java ! and this really does not satisfies me.

I wanted to ask you guys if there could be a good reason behind it ?

Comment: faster to develop. definitely not faster to run :D

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you a hard and fast answer. It seems you're looking for some sort of explanation indicating that the Ruby bindings are better than the Java ones. If this is what you're looking for it is not something we can provide. Neither language is 'better' than the other but in this case it is possibly relevant to compare the bindings. For Selenium, there is more documentation on the Java bindings and a larger userbase leading me to say that the Java bindings are actually better.

The reason for the choice of Ruby is more likely due to the skillset of your team or perhaps that using Ruby helped it fit better into your existing system.

Comment: bindings are just one part of the equation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I addressed in the final paragraph.

Comment: see my answer to see what I meant by that. note that if they use java for the app then skillset is probably not a valid reason. also, neither language is *better*, I completely agree. But for a special task, there is often a clear distinction between them. If you needed really high performance you would definitely choose java, and if that's not enough then C/C++. But you certainly wouldn't write your selenium tests in C, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby and python are both popular choices for testing because you can write very terse code in them with hardly any syntactic noise and you can use all the tools of a higher order language. Ruby is extremly strong in creating embedded DSLs which makes it an ideal candidate for testing purposes.

Java is more strict, requires more coding and the benefits in this case are negligible. You don't really need static type checking because you run your test all the time and all the code paths are constantly checked and you don't really benefit from the faster execution time of java because selenium is very slow and it's the real bottleneck.

So the quick answer is: probably because you can write the test code faster.